# Could not found method getBuilder in io.mongock.runner.springboot.config.MongockContext required a bean of type 'ConnectionDriver'

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongock

I have a problem with proper configure mongock for my project.

I have added to pom.xml dependencies:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongock-springboot</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-springdata-v3-driver</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongock-driver-mongodb-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I have added annotation on ApplicationClass: @EnableMongock

In application.yml I have added configuration:

```
mongock:
  migration-scan-package:
    - com.test.project.config.dbmigrations
  enabled: true
```

Documentation says that this setup should be enough, but when I run app I have got error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method getBuilder in io.mongock.runner.springboot.config.MongockContext required a bean of type 'io.mongock.driver.api.driver.ConnectionDriver' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'io.mongock.driver.api.driver.ConnectionDriver' in your configuration.
```

Do you know how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using spring 3.x.x version, the dependencies mentioned in documentations are not proper. Use dependencies like below in order to make autoconfiguration to work:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongock-bom</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.4</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongock-springboot-v3</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongodb-springdata-v4-driver</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Post this, your configuration in `application.yml` will work

Comment: Works but unfortunately the docs tell otherwise: https://docs.mongock.io/v5/get-started/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the version of Spring Boot you are using, this likely has different causes:

When using Spring Boot 3.x.x you need to use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongock-springboot-v3</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

instead of `mongock-springboot` as stated in [GitHub issue #589](https://github.com/mongock/mongock/issues/589).

---

If using Spring Boot 2.x.x or above change does not work, for some reason the Bean is not auto-detected.

Defining the Bean manually should solve/workaround this:

- Either use the Builder approach instead of the `@EnableMongock` Annotation.

  You can [choose](https://docs.mongock.io/v5/runner/springboot/index.html#features) between the ApplicationRunner or the InitializingBeanRunner.

  An example for such a Runner can be found in the [Mongock-examples repo](https://github.com/mongock/mongock-examples).
- Alternatively you can only define the ConnectionDriver Bean while keeping the Annotation approach with something like this:

  ```java
  @Bean
  // name of Method seems irrelevant
  public ConnectionDriver mongockConnection(MongoClient mongoClient) {
      return SpringDataMongoV3Driver.withDefaultLock(mongoClient, "your databaseName");
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

For Spring version 3.1 and Spring Boot, this worked for me in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongock-springboot-v3</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-springdata-v4-driver</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and I completely removed the property:

```
mongock.transaction-enabled=true
```

in the properties file and instead just added `@EnableMongock` annotation under `@SpringBootApplication` annotation in my application class.

Answer (score 2):

You can try by making a setup bean.

```
    @Bean
    public MongockApplicationRunner mongockApplicationRunner(
            ApplicationContext springContext,
            MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        return MongockSpringboot.builder()
                .setDriver(SpringDataMongoV3Driver.withDefaultLock(mongoTemplate))
                .addMigrationScanPackage("your_changeLog_package_path")
                .setSpringContext(springContext)
                .buildApplicationRunner();
    }
```